# Drawing Graphics with other classes

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I have two classes below: And I'm trying to make it so that calling `FilledFrame` would make certain shapes. I've tested it with a Line below, but it doesn't show up on the GUI. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? I also need to make a `Card` class that is able to modify some rectangle's positions, so would I need to make a graphics object in the main and enter it into `FilledFrame` and my `Card` class?

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FilledFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    static int FRAME_WIDTH = 500;
    static int FRAME_HEIGHT = 100;
    Graphics g = getGraphics();

    public FilledFrame () {
        g.drawLine(1, 1, 100, 100);

        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createComponents() {
        ...
    }

    private void createCards() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }

    public static void draw (Graphics g) {
        g.fillRect(0, 50, 100, 150);
    }
}
```

### Main class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D.Float;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import java.awt.Canvas;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Main {

    public static void main (String args[]) {

    FilledFrame frame = new FilledFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);           
    frame.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Sorry to say, but you're guessing at how to do Swing drawing, and while this might work with simple Java concepts, it won't for something as complex as Swing graphics.

Problems include:

- Trying to draw directly within the JFrame -- never do this, but instead draw in a JPanel.
- Calling `getGraphics()` on a component to get a Graphics resource. This will lead to your getting an unstable and short-lived Graphics object that can lead to either failed painting or NullPointerExceptions
- Not drawing in an appropriate painting method.
- You're using int literals in your drawing method parameters rather than int variables, making any drawing that you *do* do, fixed -- you can never move or change it.

Instead I suggest that you:

- Create a class that extends JPanel and paint in that class.
- Draw within this class's `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)` method.
- Don't forget to call the super's paintComponent method within your override so that your GUI cleans up any dirty pixels.
- Then place that JPanel into the JFrame that needs to display it.
- Use int fields (variables) not int literals (so-called "magic" numbers) for most of your drawing method parameters so that your drawings can change if you so desire while the program runs.
- And most important, read and study the standard Swing graphics tutorials.

Resources:

- [The Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html): the main tutorial where you should start.
- [Using Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html): how to create Swing GUI's
- [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html): introductory tutorial to Swing graphics
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html): advanced tutorial on Swing graphics